# Elasticsearch mapping integer or long

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my laravel app as an search engine.

But when it comes to mapping i am not sure whenever to use integer or long for my numbers?

I have a MySql DB that adds data live to my ES database.

I need to make my numbers searchable or sortable. Eg sort by price or search by price.

I cant find anything in the docs saying when to use integer or long.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should ask yourself if these number will ever extend 64 bit if so use long if not use int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between int and long is the size of the number that can be represented.  Basically, int is a 32 bit signed integer, and long is a 64 bit signed integer.  So, if the value you need to represent is larger than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, then you need to use a long.

To ensure that you can search/sort by your field, you need to make sure that it is indexed (not_analyzed).

Elasticserach [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) documentation.
Elasticsearch [core types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_core_datatypes) documentation.
Java [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) documentation.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure. I set it as "index : not_analyzed" ? In order to make it searchable

Comment: And since I am a real noob. How big of a "number" can i store in each? 1 - 100000 ?

Comment: @user2722667 Short answer: yes.  Longer answer: `index` has three options: 'analyzed', 'not_analyzed', and 'no'.  In order to search/sort the field, you must set `index` to either 'analyzed' or 'not_analyzed'.  For numeric fields, the 'analyzed' option doesn't make sense, so to search/sort numeric fields, you need to set `index` to 'not_analzyed'.  Pertinent documentation right [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2).

Comment: @user2722667 2^32 = 4294967296.  So, if you need a number > 4294967295, you need to use long.

Comment: thanks for making this clear to me. My pk in MySql is a incrementing number, but I should be safe when its between 1 - 4294967296, that is alot of rows..

Comment: do you have any real world example when someone would need to use "long" I mean an incrementing value in an "id" row does never hit that far?

Comment: @user2722667 It all depends on your situation.  If you have a high transaction volume table, then you need to consider that when creating your PK.  If you're creating a million rows a day, you'll have a little over a year before you hit your limit with an int.  If you're creating 10 rows a day, then you'll have one million worry-free years.  That being said, yes, I've dealt with systems that have hit the limit.

Comment: Actually, `integer` is limited by 2^31 since it's signed. Check out the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html.

Comment: @VitalyChirkov You are correct, it should be 2^31, not 2^32. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the maximum value that will be stored for your numeric fields, then, I would suggest to go for the exact type that is enough for your field. ie, do not use `long`, if `integer` is enough. The docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use  explicitly mentions this :

```
As far as integer types (byte, short, integer and long) are concerned, you should pick the smallest type which is enough for your use-case. This will help indexing and searching be more efficient
```